# Workflow - Accepting/rejecting individual changes

Tags: workflows

Is there a way to accept/reject individual changes in the workflow process? If so, how and/or what modules are the best to do this?

Comment: What workflow solution are you using?

Comment: I am using the http://drupal.org/project/workflow module @MPD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had frustration with the Workflow module. You may want to try out the Workbench and Workbench Moderation modules. Throw in the Trigger module to send e-mail notifications when a document changes workflow state.